# jsoup get the next div element

Tags: java, jsoup

How can I get the first div after the h1 tag  .

**The html:**

```
<h1> Shalom </h1>
<b> Tov </b>
<div>  ddd  </div> <! I need to take this div >
```

**My java jsoup code**

```
Elements apresh =  doc.select("h1 ~ div"); 
String csdsdsdf =    apresh.html(); 
System.out.printf(csdsdsdf);
```

But it doesn't work. Can you help me ?

Comment: "code to get the next div after the ." which .?

Comment: Sorry @MichaelMontero How can I get the first div after the h1 tag

Comment: To see the html code of the div. To check.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have mentioned in the comments, I believe you are trying to extract the first element from the matching elements based on your selector `"h1 ~ div"`.

You can use the below provided method from the API.

[public Element first()](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#first--): Get the first matched element.

Answer (score 0):

I've found two ways to do this:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<h1> Shalom </h1>" +
                               "<b> Tov </b>" + 
                               "<div>  ddd  </div>");

    // 1 Select DIV which is after B which is after H1.
    System.out.println(doc.select("h1 + b + div"));

    // 2 More flexible solution which involves going one level up to parent 
    //   and then selecting the first DIV.
    System.out.println(doc.select("h1").first().parent().select("div").first());
```